# Map is blury when rendered using 100% height in css in Leaflet JS library

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

The rendered map appears blurry in Chrome `Version 49.0.2623.110 m` when using `100% Height` in CSS.

I am using LeafletJS library version `0.7.7`.

I only support zoom level `6,7 & 8` so at zoom level `6`, it looks like this:

[image]

If I zoom even to max capability, which is `8`, it looks quite blurry like this:

[image]

This is my **index.html** (implementation source):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Europe Zoom Level 6 & 7</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            html { height: 100% }
            body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            #map { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function () {

                // Objects
                var isOnline = false;
                var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 6);;

                // Generate tile layer url
                var tileLayerUrl = isOnline
                    ? 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    : 'MapQuest/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';

                // Set tile layer & add to map
                L.tileLayer(tileLayerUrl, {
                    minZoom : 6,
                    maxZoom : 8,
                    attribution: '&copy; <a target="_blank" href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                })
                .addTo(map);

                // Test marker
                L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
                    .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a <u>html</u> popup.");

            })();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a fix for this?

---

On a separate note, In Internet Explorer (`11`) it looks crystal clear:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turns out it's still blurry even if I don't use 100% height css. I tested it with online tiles also and they are also blurry.

Comment: I believe blurry text is a sign that you should try to enable hardware graphics acceleration (or at least google and read up on it). I  There are a few ways to that, but I believe `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on your parent div is the popular way of doing it. There are some drawbacks (like memory consumption) but generally you gain performance. I stems from using css-animations I believe. CSS animations in webkit browsers are blurry OR use hardware acc with anti-aliasing. I am not sure if that is something you can disable in google map.

Comment: It's not just the text, it's the map tiles also (as per my screenshot). Will this `transform` trick help? Do i apply it to the `<div id="map" ...` ?

Comment: I tried applying it to the map div as well as body, it did not help.

Comment: Sorry I should just be quiet. It was some time ago I looked at this stuff. (I'm still convinced that is your problem, but not of the solution.)

Comment: Do other Leaflet maps also look blurry in Chrome, or do you only experience this problem with this particular map?